# Asynchronous function modifying .txt file causes program to hang/freeze

Tags: python, asynchronous, text, file-io, python-asyncio

Here is a simplified version of my function that upon sending a few web-requests and making a few checks proceeds to modify a certain .txt file which name is contained in the variable `filename_partners`:

```
async def add_partner(session, user_id):
    user_premium_request = await session.get(SOME_REQUEST)
    
    if (await user_premium_request.content.read())[-145:-141] == b"true":
    
        with open(filename_partners, "r+") as partners_library:
            file = partners_library.read()
    
        if (str(user_id) + ":") in file:
            pass
        else:
            user_item_id_list = []
            user_item_request = await session.get(SOME_REQUEST)
            user_items_list = json.loads(await user_item_request.text())["data"]

            for item in user_items_list:
                user_item_id_list.append(item["assetId"])
            if len(user_item_id_list) >= 1:
                with open(filename_partners, "a+") as partners_library:
                    partners_library.write("\n" + str(user_id) + ":" + str(time.time()))
    else:
        with open(filename_partners, "r+") as partners_library:
            file = partners_library.read()

            if (str(user_id) + ":") in file:
                lines = file.splitlines()
                cursor_token = lines[0]

                with open(filename_partners_temp, "a+") as partners_library_temp:
                    partners_library_temp.write(cursor_token)
                    for line in lines[1:]:
                        if (str(user_id) + ":") in line:
                            partners_library_temp.write(
                                "\n"
                                + str(user_id)
                                + ":"
                                + str(time.time() + 2592000)
                            )

                        else:
                            partners_library_temp.write("\n" + line)
    
                    partners_library_temp.seek(0)
                    new_file = partners_library_temp.read()
    
                    with open(filename_partners, "w+") as partners_library_2:
                        partners_library_2.write(new_file)
    
                os.remove(filename_partners_temp)
```

The issue is, for my program, I have to call this function 1,000s of times, which might take a very long time. To combat it, I decided to call it concurrently:

```
# seller_ids is a list of 200-300 items
for user_id in seller_ids:
    tasks.append(add_partner(session, user_id))
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

However, doing so causes my program to freeze/hang after 2-20 minutes of running. No errors are triggered, and I am fairly certain that what causes it is the fact that I am calling a lot of .txt-modifying functions concurrently. To test my theory, I tried to call them consecutively:

```
for user_id in seller_ids_clear:
    await add_partner(session, user_id)
```

After running my program that way, it was no longer freezing/hanging, however, it was running about 10 times slower, which is an issue in my case.

I am sure that file operations are to blame here, but I am not sure how calling that async function concurrently 100s of times can cause my program to freeze with no errors being displayed. If anyone here has more experience with file operations and asyncio, please do let me know your suggestions and theories!

**UPDATE:** It seems like the program as a whole is not freezing, but only the `add_partner()` function freezes/hangs, causing a big part of the program to indefinitely wait for it to finish, while other parts of the program, not connected with `add_partner()` whatsoever, continue to function normally.

Comment: Which OS are you running the program on?

Comment: @user4815162342 Windows 10, the program is only supposed to run on Windows.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the non-simplified version of the function...

Comment: @user4815162342 I just removed error-handling and cut down on the web-requests part. The file-modifying part of the function was not changed.

Comment: Still, maybe there's a part that makes a difference. For example, do you have awaits inside any of the `with open(...)` blocks?

Comment: @user4815162342 Just double-checked, and no, there is no `await` parts inside `with open()` sections of the function. All `with open()` parts of the function were just copy-pasted from my program, unchanged.

Comment: I thought maybe some of the file IO operations deadlocks due to interaction with another `add_partner` instance. But without `await` inside `with open()`, I don't see how it could happen - it shouldn't matter how many instances of `add_partner` run "in parallel", they will only yield execution when awaiting, and  all the awaits are outside the file ops.

Comment: Try unindenting all code below the second occurrence of `with open(filename_partners, "r+"): as partners_library: file = partners_library.read()` (the one in the `else` block), i.e. unindent line 24 and everything below it. You read the whole file immediately anyway, so you gain nothing by keeping the file open, and perhaps you are creating issues with other coroutines running in parallel and trying to open the same file for writing.

Comment: @user4815162342 Hmm, I tried changing indent as you suggested, but the program still freezes on that function. I might have to just do a timeout for that function's execution.

Comment: Try peppering the function with prints until you figure out **where** it freezes (and what happened immediately before that). Once you are aware of where the problem lies, fixing it might become obvious.